# start ubuntu service as user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, services, ubuntu-server

I am trying to create a service in ubuntu server, whitch I need to start as a user. Main reason I need to do that is that I need to call it from www(php script).

lets say I got this script called demostart2, and when I start it as user I got this error:

```
service demostart2 start
```

start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.12" (uid=1000 pid=15085 comm="start demostart2 ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

Is it possible to start service as user? I tried chown that file, but notthing happend.
Thank you

Comment: As what user did you execute this command? Does something like this `sudo -u www-data service demostart2 start` give the same error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this server is using an enhanced security model (possibly SELinux, but more likely AppArmour).  You would need to update the security profile  or disable the Mandatory Access Control.